# iOS JSON NSString Parse

Tags: ios, json

I have a JSON string as an NSString object in iOS. I want to parse this and pull out the given parameters in the JSON string. Is there a efficient way to parse this or is the only way to search for substrings etc.?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The way to do it with iOS 5 is to use the `NSJSONSerialization` class.  You will want to first convert your string to an NSData object, and call the class method `JSONObjectWithData`

```
NSData *jsonData = [myJsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *e;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:nil error:&e];
```

Note that `JSONObjectWithData` will return either an NSDictionary or an NSArray, depending whether your JSON string represents an a dictionary or an array.

Comment: Notice that you should use 0 or NSJSONReadingMutableContainers for the options to suppress the compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

A good framework for converting JSON strings to Objective-C objects (`NSArray` and `NSDictionary`) is [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) ([Github](https://github.com/stig/json-framework)).

Usage:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [myJsonString JSONValue];
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with iOS 5 JSON?

Comment: Yes, but it is more involved and limits your application to running only on iOS 5.

Comment: I agree, SBJSON is your friend.  Much more convenient than the official API, and works with older iOS versions too.