# Unable to create keys into NSDictionary after parsing JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have seen similar topics to this but none that seem to address my issue.  I am receiving this JSON:

```
("taskname: 1738 Main St., taskdescription: install flooring, worker: Jim Davis, approver: John Jones",
"taskname: 300 Market St., taskdescription: paint ceiling, worker: John Smith, approver: Bob Johnson"
)
```

This is the code that I am using to ultimately create a NSDictionary:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:MY_JSON_URL];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:NULL];
NSArray *JSONarray = [JSONDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"feed.entry.content.$t"];

NSDictionary *taskDictionary = JSONarray[0];

NSLog(@"array content = %@",JSONarray)
```

The array values are correct but when I try to key into the dictionary, the key does not exist

```
NSLog(@"dictionary contents = %@", taskDictionary[@"taskname"]);
```

I am new to JSON so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This is not valid JSON. It's neither an array `[ "object1", "object2" ]` nor a dictionary `{ "key1" : "object1", "key2" : "object2" }`

Comment: This is more like an array not a JSON.

Comment: Array of strings. right ? you could [JSON Parse from NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200790/ios-json-nsstring-parse) but your string is not valid JSON type too

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you are receiving is not valid, hence the key 'taskname' doesn't exist.
It should be in the following format:

```
[{"taskname": "1738 Main St.", "taskdescription": "install flooring", "worker": "Jim Davis", "approver": "John Jones"},
{"taskname": "300 Market St.", "taskdescription": "paint ceiling", "worker": "John Smith", "approver": "Bob Johnson"}]
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, that is what I suspected.  Since all of the information is there, Is there any way to convert what I am receiving into a format that would be acceptable for NSDictionary?

Comment: It's a bit dirty, but you can try and edit the string by replacing ': ' with '": "' and ', ' with '", "'. Then you should have a valid JSON string